# Are questions about the process of creating specific literary works on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just to be clear, I'm NOT talking about generic "how to write" questions; that would be on-topic on writers.SE (and imho should be off-topic here).

I mean things like:

> **What did this specific literature work's creators do to achieve that result?**

Example question I had in mind:

[What mechanism does David Weber use to ensure internal consistency of works in the shared Honorverse?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17/what-mechanism-does-david-weber-use-to-ensure-internal-consistency-of-works-in-t)

Comment: Are you asking about literary analysis? I was going to ask a more general question about it.

Comment: @Gallifreian - not quite, more the process of creating specific books.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes.**

1. As these questions would be relating to a specific work or author, there is a defined scope.
2. Depending on the age of the work, there may be interviews and articles discussing this with the author. This would give us "canon" / "word-of-god" definitive answers not based on speculation.
3. As you mentioned these are about already written works and not "how to's", which I agree would be better on the Writers Stack.